# why I'm getting this error message "critical error encountered" in visual studio 2015 pro

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm getting this error message in visual studio 2015 pro saying that "Critical error encountered" and need to restart visual studio.

error description

> ms vs database project has encountered a critical error and must exit. do you want to try to save your solution and any open document before exiting

log

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.MetadataProvider.Features.OnlineMetadataCache..ctor()
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.MetadataProvider.Features.OnlineMetadataCache.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.DesignerServices.OnlineProject.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.DesignerServices.DatabaseChangesManager.TryDisposeModel(SqlDatabaseLocation database, Boolean forceCleanup)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.DesignerServices.DatabaseChangesManager.CleanupModels(Boolean forceCleanup)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.DesignerServices.DatabaseChangesManager.PollBufferChangesJob.Run()
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Utilities.Sql.Common.Threading2.JobManager.JobBase.<Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Utilities.Sql.Common.Threading2.JobManager.IManageableJob.RunImpl>b__22_0(Object )
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Utilities.Sql.Common.Threading2.JobManager.JobBase.Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Utilities.Sql.Common.Threading2.JobManager.IManageableJob.RunImpl(Object dummyArg)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Utilities.Sql.Common.Threading2.JobManager.RunCurrentThread(IManageableJob imj)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Utilities.Sql.Common.Threading2.JobManager.RunIdleCooperatively()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.IdleProcessingComponent.FDoIdle(UInt32 grfidlef)
```

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error (working on an Azure SQL V12 database).  When investigating, I found out it was because I used "cross apply string_split(" functionality. (which works fine in the database)
It seems the parser in Visual Studio 2015 really does not like this....same goes for some other new functions.....

Update 20170606: I updated DAXFX and SSDT to the latest versions (17.1 and 14.0.61705.170), and now it works without problems.
See [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/2906200/ssdt-failing-to-compile-if-string-split-is-used) on microsoft connect)

Regards,
Gerard